# Oracle How delete duplicates based on multiples database columns and conditions

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a very huge table with data collected from multiple systems. I now have to delete duplicate records based on conditions and multiple columns.

Here is an example:

```
 +---------------+-------------+------+-----+--------
| System ID     | Debt Num    | Exp Dt | Account NO |
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------
| pay           | 2222        | 0114   |   111      |
| pay           | 2222        | 0214   |   111      |
| Online        | 2222        | 0214   |   111      |
| Online        | 3333        | 0115   |   222      |
| Online        | 3333        | 0116   |   222      |
| ERP           | 2222        | 0214   |   111      | 
| ERP           | 4444        | 0114   |   333      | 
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+--------
```

From the above data , delete the duplicates with the following conditions satisfied.

- Delete the duplicate rows group by debit num , exp dt , account-no and keep one record with max(exp dt).
- Records to be retained is based of priority to `System ID`. 1) pay 2) Online and 3) ERP.  In the above for the account 111 we have records from all three systems and max(exp dt) of the debit card is 0214 of all three system. Only the record from `Pay` with exp dt=0214 should be retained and rest should be deleted.
- As above example for account 222 , we dont have records from pay and hence give priority to system Online and the ERP out of which the max(exp dt) should be retained.

I have tried multiple queries found online , like group by, row_number over but all fulfill just one condition.

Appreciate your help to contribute your thoughts and suggestions.

`EDIT`:
Gordon's query works fine and fits my requirements, however when I ran the same on staging which contains 540K rows, it error out ORA-00600 Internal error.

Comment: Have you looked into the Oracle MERGE command?

Comment: @scraatz not until now. I just had a look at example `merge into when matched .. when not matched from http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/merge-enhancements-10g.php. Is this correct? do you have better reference? BTW, nice thought and good suggestion. I will try out.

Comment: Sorry, I only recently found it when trying to solve a similar problem . I Googled for "oracle delete from join" as on other databases you can delete from joined tables which is not possible on Oracle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do this with `rowid` and a correlated subquery:

```
delete from payinfo_staging_db
   where rowid <> (select rowid
                   from (select rowid
                         from payinfo_staging_db t2
                         where t2.debitNum = payinfo_staging_db.debitNum and
                               t2.accountNo = payinfo_staging_db.accountNo
                         order by t2.exp_dt,
                                  (case when t2.SystemId = 'Pay' then 1
                                        when t2.SystemId = 'Online' then 2
                                        when t2.SystemId = 'ERP' then 3
                                   end)
                        ) r
                    where rownum = 1
                  );
```

EDIT:

There must be a problem with nested references in Oracle.  The following works (at least in the sense that it parses and executes correctly):

```
delete from payinfo_staging_db
   where rowid <> (select min(rowid) keep (dense_rank first order by exp_dt desc,
                                                            (case when t2.SystemId = 'Pay' then 1
                                                                  when t2.SystemId = 'Online' then 2
                                                                  when t2.SystemId = 'ERP' then 3
                                                             end)
                                          ) as therowid
                   from payinfo_staging_db t2
                   where t2.debitNum = payinfo_staging_db.debitNum and
                         t2.accountNo = payinfo_staging_db.accountNo
                  );
```

The SQL Fiddle is [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/12348/6).

Comment: I tried the above and notice error t.debitNum:invalid identified. Is the table alias `t` valid in the sub query?

Comment: What is the name of your table?

Comment: my table name is payinfo_staging_db , i replaced `from t` as `payinfo_staging_db t` same for `from t t2` as `from payinfo_staging_db t2`. Hope this is correct.

Comment: I see the edit now and I already tried that. Same error ORA-00904."payinfo_staging_db":"debitNum" invalid identifier.

Comment: I missed one point mentioned, I didn't run 'delete' statement instead I changed to 'select * from payinfo_staging_db' , i wanted to see what rows it return first and then delete.

Comment: @dicaprio . . . It had the same problem with `delete`.  Your strategy is a good one.

Comment: Great ! this works. However,I fail to understand how this `case` condition helping.

Comment: @dicaprio . . . This chooses one row, the first based on the order by.  The first clause on date gets the most recent date.  Then it is ordered by the system, based on your preferences.

Comment: ORA-00600 internal error code . Received this error when I ran the same query on DB containing  540K rows.